# Sticky element wont exit with parent

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to create a behavior where I have a series of containers that behave like sliding cards. Each card represents a year in my portfolio, they have some amount of content, then slide up and stick only showing the year. I've tried to follow a tutorial from css tricks, which I've linked below, but my prototype seems to be heavily bugged out.

[CSS Tricks stacked card tut](https://css-tricks.com/stacked-cards-with-sticky-positioning-and-a-dash-of-sass/)

I would absolutely appreciate any help on solving this.

A sample of my code below:

```css
.flex-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  height: -webkit-fit-content;
  height: -moz-fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.seperator {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}

.card {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
}

.card:nth-child(1n) {
  top: 2rem;
}

.card:nth-child(2n) {
  top: 4rem;
}

.card:nth-child(3n) {
  top: 6rem;
}

.card:nth-child(4n) {
  top: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;">
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 200vh; display: unset;">
  <div class="card seperator ">
    <div class="flex-bar">
      <div style="font-size: 2em;">2021</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card seperator ">
    <div class="flex-bar">
      <div style="font-size: 2em;">2020</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card seperator ">
    <div class="flex-bar">
      <div style="font-size: 2em;">2019</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card seperator">
    <div class="flex-bar">
      <div style="font-size: 2em;">2018</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="about" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;">
```

I have attached a codepen which has a demonstration of the exit behavior- On scrolling up the title exits.

Similarly in my sample I want the .card containers to exhibit a similar behaviour when the body ends. Notably I don't want just the title to stick, I want the whole card to stick.(Note: edited for clarity)

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/rpsthecoder/pen/mjoMMm)

Basically I want it to be like how the titles stick while their parent is still in the screen, but then leave once their parent exits the screen. I can't seem to replicate this behavior whatever I do.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `card` and `seperator` classes are the container elements that hold everything in each section. Beacuse of this, you do not want to assign the `position: sticky;` value to these classes. Instead, you want to assign `position: sticky;` to the title/header element, which in this case is your `flex-bar` class (specifically the child `<div>` inside that class).

You will also need to set the `top` property as well, as `position: sticky;` needs some sort of positioning data to know where it will position the element in relation to its container.

```css
.flex-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  height: -webkit-fit-content;
  height: -moz-fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.seperator {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}

.card {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.card:nth-child(1n) {
  top: 2rem;
}

.card:nth-child(2n) {
  top: 4rem;
}

.card:nth-child(3n) {
  top: 6rem;
}

.card:nth-child(4n) {
  top: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;">
</div>
<div class="fix" style="width: 100%; height: 200vh; display: unset;">
  <div class="card seperator ">
    <div class="flex-bar">
      <div style="font-size: 2em;">2021</div>
      <div>This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card seperator ">
    <div class="flex-bar">
      <div style="font-size: 2em;">2020</div> 
      <div>This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card seperator ">
    <div class="flex-bar">
      <div style="font-size: 2em;">2019</div>
            <div>This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card seperator">
    <div class="flex-bar">
      <div style="font-size: 2em;">2018</div>
            <div>This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page. This is sample content. It is only used as an example of content or information on the page that also expands the element on the page.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="about" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;">
```

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure I follow this logic. There will likely be multiple flex-boxes in each section, and assigning sticky only to the header would only make the header stick and not the rest of the content?

Comment: i apologize if i was not clear before, I have edited it for clarity.

Comment: @PranavNair Any elements inside of the `flex-bar` class will also be sticky. Right now there is only 1 `<div>` element with the year. If you place other elements inside of the `flex-bar` element, all of those elements will also be sticky and stay until the next section is reached. I have added to my example to demonstrate this.

Comment: It should also be noted that I am only answering the posted question. There are a lot of unusual behaviors with the content depending on the window size and content used. Because no content has been provided (only titles/headers), I cannot accommodate all scenarios.